# how can i add each value entered in my TD using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a list of rows and columns. basically the first_value and second_value column is an input type where the user can enter and the `total` column is a span. how can i add the first_value and second_value column to its specific row?

```
ID|    first_value |    second value |     total
1        0                 50                50
2        20                0                 20
3        10                0                 10
4        20                10                30
5        10                0                 10
```

```
here is my html/php code

<table class="table table-striped" id="user_set_goal_table" width="100%">
                         <thead>
                             <tr>
                                 <th>#</th>
                                 <th>First_value</th>
                                 <th>Second_value</th>
                                 <th>total</th>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                                                 for($i=1;$i<=16;$i++){
                         ?>
                         <tr>
                             <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<input type='text'  class='navigate_TD_ID' id='first_value".$i."'  "; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo "<input type='text' class='navigate_TD_ID'  id='second_value".$i."'  "; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<span id='total".$i." '></span>"?></td>
                         </tr>
                         <?php
                         }
                         </tbody>
```

```
javascript code:

    $('.navigate_TD_ID').on('change', function() {
        var input_id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(input_id);
    });
```

i can already get which id the user click on TD but i dont know how will i implement this calculations, i mean how can i calculate and display to its specific position in row. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Since you know the td of the clicked element, you can navigate upwards through nodes to the parent _row_ and the parent _table_. Use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to place it at the position you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to find the `span` relative to the `input` that raised the event. Specifically, use the `this` reference along with `closest()` and `find()`.

Also note that it's better practice to use common classes on repeated content, instead of generating dynamic `id` attributes. Try this:

```js
$('.first, .second').on('input', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var f = parseFloat($tr.find('.first').val()) || 0;
  var s = parseFloat($tr.find('.second').val()) || 0;
  $tr.find('.total').text(f + s);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="user_set_goal_table" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First_value</th>
      <th>Second_value</th>
      <th>total</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="navigate first" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="navigate second" /></td>
      <td><span class="total"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="navigate first" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="navigate second" /></td>
      <td><span class="total"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick example with **vanilla js** and without **PHP**

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="user_set_goal_table" width="50%">
   <thead style="text-align:left;">
       <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First_value</th>
          <th>Second_value</th>
          <th>total</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>

    // table body
    let tbody =  document.querySelectorAll('table tbody')[0];
    // trs
    let rows  = tbody.children;

    // fill table body
    for(let j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
        tbody.innerHTML += `
            <td>${j}</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="first"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="second"></td>
            <td><span></span></td>
        `;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        let firstInput  = rows[i].children[1].firstElementChild;
        let secondInput = rows[i].children[2].firstElementChild;
        let total       = rows[i].children[3].firstElementChild;

        [firstInput, secondInput].forEach((elem) => {

            elem.addEventListener('input' ,(e) => {

                let first     = e.target.value;
                let second  = (e.target.className == "first") ? secondInput.value : firstInput.value;

                total.innerText = parseFloat(first) + parseFloat(second);
            });

        });
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]